# Set / update the Current User's cache / localstorage data. Parse JS SDK

Tags: javascript, session, parse-platform, local-storage

When Parse.User.current() Object sets some new values and gets saved, the Object is sync, but on page reload, the Object gets back to the former state (old values).

When i logout then login again, the values are now sync. Whenever Parse.User.current().save() is done, the cache / localstorage doesn't seem to be updated.

Is there a method to update / refresh the cached data on the browser ? Except from editing the localstorage without the SDK methods ?

Very weird behaviour btw.

Comment: O that's exactly what I'm experiencing. Even calling fetch() on Parse.User.current() doesn't update the local storage cached user. Have you found the solution?

Comment: It seems like it's been fixed in 1.6.9 but not yet on CDN

Comment: @Varandpezeshk i used a workaround where i update the localstorage myself but it's not really a good practice i think, hope to see it on the CDN soon